# python - get specific value on json

Tags: python, json

I want to get every value of 'Lemma' in this json:

```
{'sentences': 
   [{'indexeddependencies': [], 'words': 
     [
        ['Cinnamomum', {'CharacterOffsetBegin': '0', 'CharacterOffsetEnd': '10', 'Lemma': 'Cinnamomum', 'PartOfSpeech': 'NNP', 'NamedEntityTag': 'O'}], 
        ['.', {'CharacterOffsetBegin': '14', 'CharacterOffsetEnd': '15', 'Lemma': '.', 'PartOfSpeech': '.', 'NamedEntityTag': 'O'}]
     ], 'parsetree': [], 'text': 'Cinnamomum.', 'dependencies': []
    }, 
    {'indexeddependencies': [], 'words': 
      [
        ['specific', {'CharacterOffsetBegin': '16', 'CharacterOffsetEnd': '24', 'Lemma': 'specific', 'PartOfSpeech': 'JJ', 'NamedEntityTag': 'O'}],
        ['immunoglobulin', {'CharacterOffsetBegin': '25', 'CharacterOffsetEnd': '39', 'Lemma': 'immunoglobulin', 'PartOfSpeech': 'NN', 'NamedEntityTag': 'O'}],
        ['measurement', {'CharacterOffsetBegin': '51', 'CharacterOffsetEnd': '62', 'Lemma': 'measurement', 'PartOfSpeech': 'NN', 'NamedEntityTag': 'O'}]
      ], 'parsetree': [], 'text': 'specific immunoglobulin measurement', 'dependencies': []
     }]
}
```

How can I get every value using python? There are five Lemma keys but I can't get all of them.

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
for i in range(len(words)): #in this case the range of i would be 5
      lemma = result["sentences"][0]["words"][i][1]["Lemma"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. change single quotes to double quotes by `sed -i 's/\'/\"/g' sample.json`
2. convert to json object and parse it by module `json`

   `import json
   with open('sample.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
   data = json.loads(data_file.read())
   for sentence in data['sentences']:
       for word in sentence['words']:
           print(word[1]['Lemma'])`

Result:

`Cinnamomum
.
specific
immunoglobulin
measurement`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why do you have this data structure - assuming you cannot change/reshape it to better suit your queries and use cases and that `Lemma` key would always be present:

```
>>> [word[1]['Lemma'] 
     for sentence in data['sentences'] 
     for word in sentence['words']]
['Cinnamomum', '.', 'specific', 'immunoglobulin', 'measurement']
```

Answer (score 0):

this simple code traverses everything and finds all Lemma values (btw. your json should have " instead of ' as string quotes, I guess:

```
import json

with open('lemma.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)


def traverse(node):
    for key in node:
        if isinstance(node, list):
            traverse(key)
        elif isinstance(node, dict):
            if key == 'Lemma':
                print key, node[key]
                continue
            traverse(node[key])

traverse(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JSON encoder and decoder library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

If you use that library you write:

`import json
json.loads(result)`

Anyway, i try put your json in a validator and i obtain a error

Comment: i changed single quote to double quotes and then use json.loads(), and it works